# Selecting Features by Expression in QGIS

Tags: select-by-expression

I have a set of features in a single layer that have been created during various periods of time.

In a layer attribute table, there is a column `kreirao_datum` which means created on a date

[image: In a layer attribute table, there is a column kreirao_datum which means created on a date]

I would like to select all features created within a single calendar year, for example 2021, using 'Select by Expression', but I can not figure out how to write the expression.

It should probably be something like  "`kreirao_datum" = '2021-07-29T09:45:01.000'`, and it works for a single matching record.

But how can I write expression that would select all records created within a 2021 year, `"kreirao_datum" = '2021_????'`?

[image]

I am very well aware that I can use Filter within attribute table, and it also works, but I am trying to determine what would be the right expression for 'Select by Expression'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use function [`year()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#year) to extract the year form your date:

`year ("kreirao_datum") = 2021`

[image]

Answer (score 3):

@Babel has the right answer because this is a neat datetime column but if there wouldn't be (or if there is some weirdness going on below the screenshot) there are more tools available under the "String" section.

[image]

Mostly, the `left`, `right` and `substr` functions can clip out parts of the date string. If you are really desperate you can use the various regex functions or `strpos` to search the column for the year but this has a danger and might match a month-day like 2002 (20 februari) with the year.